# mvc button value click not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am stuck at a problem for the past couple of days and it just baffles me. So in this form I have two file upload inputs, three buttons one with value of create, cancel and populate.  Users browse and selects a file, and hit the Upload button whose submitted value is populate in my action method, i save files, have a static class to parse the data using state machine yield etc and some json serialization and save the file in the appdata/uploads folder.when they hit cancel i do some functionality and when they hit create i dont parse the data but just save it. all button inputs post to the same action method on this page.  Whats happening is everything works perfect on the local machine, on my testing environment on a server, it seems that the populate routine does not even run. I even added a try catch and log to exception table but nothing works. i cannot debug on the test environment. let alone the parsing, if the user had selected a file  and hit o populate, it first check if the file format is in the correct format, i try to throw an exception there by attaching an invalid format and it does not even catch that. Now whats funny is in my save button click within the same action method, if i attach an invalid file, my error handling catches the error. im just baffled. please suggest!!

```
 <legend>Enter a new Run Log Entry</legend>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="exception">@(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)</div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">Load List File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" style="width: 500px" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                if (Model.LoadListStoredFileName != null)
                                   {
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">Attached Load List: </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.ActionLink(Model.LoadListStoredFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.LoadListStoredFileName })
                    </span>
                </div>
                                   }
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">Output File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file2" style="width: 500px" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                if (Model.OutputStoredFileName != null)
                                   {
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">Attached Output: </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.ActionLink(Model.OutputStoredFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.OutputStoredFileName })
                    </span>
                </div>
                                   }
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">Import Files: </span>
                    <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Populate" style="width: 100px">
                        Upload</button>
                    <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Remove" style="width: 100px">
                        Remove</button>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Operator")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.DropDownList("OperatorID", String.Empty)
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Run ID")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">[Generated] </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Run Start Date / Time")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunDate)
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.DropDownList("Hour", ListHelpers.HourList())
                        :
                        @Html.DropDownList("Minute", ListHelpers.Minute15List())
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.DropDownList("AMPM", ListHelpers.AMPMList())
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("System")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.DropDownList("SystemID", String.Empty)
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Run Type")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.DropDownList("RunTypeID", String.Empty)
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Run Description")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RunDescription, new { style = "width: 600px; height=30px" })
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Assay Performance Issues")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.DropDownList("AssayPerformanceIssues1", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Requested")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsRequested)
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Completed")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsCompleted)
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Run Status")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.DropDownList("RunStatusID", String.Empty)
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Assay")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedAssayIDs, new MultiSelectList(RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.AssayListItems(), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedAssayIDs))
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Error Code")
                    </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="ChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">Click
                        here to Select Error Codes</span>
                        <br />
                        <span id="ErrorCodeDisplay" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">@(Model.ErrorDescription)</span>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ErrorDescription)
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Service Entry Request")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ServiceRequest", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent">
                        @Html.Label("Problem Description")
                    </span><span class="rightContent">
                        @Html.TextArea("ProblemDescription", new { style = "width: 600px; height: 30px" })
                    </span>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input id="LogType" type="hidden" value="Run" />
                    <input id="ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    @if (Model.ExitCode == "1")
                    {
                        @Html.Hidden("ExitCode", Model.ExitCode)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input id="ExitCode" type="hidden" value='0' />
                    }
                </p>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxReplicateId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinReplicateId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputFileName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputStoredFileName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListFileName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListStoredFileName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinTestCompletionDate)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxTestCompletionDate)
                <div class="bodyContent">
                    <span class="leftContent"></span><span class="rightContent">
                        <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Create">
                            Create</button></span>
                </div>
            }
        </fieldset>

Now the controller action method as follows:

   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(RunLogEntry runLogEntry, String ServiceRequest, string Hour, string Minute, string AMPM,
                                     string submit, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, String AssayPerformanceIssues1)
        {

 if (submit == "Create")
            {


                    if (file.ElementAt(0) != null && !file.ElementAt(0).FileName.Contains("json"))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please attach a valid .JSON file for Load List selection");
                    }

                    if (file.ElementAt(1) != null && !file.ElementAt(1).FileName.Contains("out"))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please attach a valid .OUT file for Load List selection");
                    }

           }


if (submit == "Populate")
            {
try
{
if (file.Count() > 0)
    {
                        foreach (var modelValue in ModelState.Values)
                        {
                            modelValue.Errors.Clear();
                        }

                        if (file.ElementAt(0) != null && !file.ElementAt(0).FileName.Contains("json"))
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please attach a valid .JSON file for Load List selection");
                        }
                        else if (file.ElementAt(0) != null)
                        {
                            //If users are attaching another file, delete previous one
                            if ((System.IO.File.Exists(runLogEntry.LoadListStoredFileName)))
                                System.IO.File.Delete(runLogEntry.LoadListStoredFileName);

                            //Save LoadList File:
                            DateTime uploadDate = DateTime.Now;
                            string destinationPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}\\", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), uploadDate.ToString("yyyy"), uploadDate.ToString("MMM"), uploadDate.ToString("dd"));
                            if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add logger to application (for example log4net) and watch what exactly happening here.
You have few tags with same names. Is it possible, that it triggers some side-effect?

Comment: yes its due to html 4 iis, it was not rendering correctly on server